# After starting to update apps through the iPod touch, then updating them using iTunes, I now have unremovable 'Waiting' grey apps on my iPod touch

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I started updating a bunch of my iPod touch apps I realised there was too much to download over WiFi so I paused the updates, downloaded them with iTunes and synced my iPod.

Since then I have a bunch of grey icons that say 'Waiting' that I can't delete.  I've tried syncing and restoring from an earlier backup, but that hasn't worked.  Is there any way to get rid of these without doing a full restore through iTunes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, nothing worked, but two days later I checked the iPod & the icons were gone.  I hadn't changed anything, it was like it finally figued out they weren't really applications.  Wierd

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting these apps in iTunes, re-syncing, and then installing them again from the App Store.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Short of doing a full restore, you could try going into Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings. This should remove everything from your iPod (media, apps and app settings), so do not do it unless you have a backup of all your music.

As long as you have iTunes set to take backups (like it does by default) you should not loose any data. It would just sync back over next time you plug your iPod in.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to avoid loosing all my app data

Comment: @Glenn - A restore from backup will get you your data back but a restore is a lengthy process.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - I think I found the answer though:

When it turns grey and says wait, it probably means that the App Store needs another verification of your password. Click on App Store and the store will probably give you a pop up asking you to type in your password. Enter it and iTunes will probably go back to downloading the game.

If this doesn't work try downloading a new game and type in the password - hopefully it will start downloading again.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a hard reset. Hold down the power button and completely turn it off then hold it again until the Apple appears.